# How does DontSaveSensitive mode and sensitive parameter in case of a deployment work?

Tags: ssis

Suppose I have parameter marked as sensitive. And the package security mode is DontSaveSensitive.

When I save this package. Then when anyone opens the package the sensitive info will have to be reentered. However when such a package is deployed, then how does sensitive info get stored on the server when the package security mode is DontSaveSensitive?

Answer (score 0):

The DontSaveSensitive flag is not carried into the catalog.

You can set/save the parameter's values once it's deployed.

Within the catalog there is a "sensitive" flag which will influence how the UI displays the data and alters how the parameter value is stored.

You can take a peek at the catalog tables to get a closer look at the internals.

```
select * from SSISDB.internal.object_parameters
```